# Load custom trained spaCy model

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am trying to load a spaCy text classification model that I trained previously. After training, the model was saved into the `en_textcat_demo-0.0.0.tar.gz` file.

I want to use this model in a jupyter notebook, but when I do

```
import spacy
spacy.load("spacy_files/en_textcat_demo-0.0.0.tar.gz")
```

I get

```
OSError: [E053] Could not read meta.json from spacy_files/en_textcat_demo-0.0.0.tar.gz
```

What is the correct way to load my model here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either unzip the tar.gz file or install it with pip.

If you unzip it, that will result in a directory, and you can give the directory name as an argument to spaCy load.

If you use `pip install`, it will be put with your other libraries, and you can use the model name like you would with a pretrained spaCy model.

Comment: Thanks! I used `pip install path/en_textcat_demo-0.0.0.tar.gz` and was able to load the model using `spacy.load("en_textcat_demo")`